# Is ruby controller params escaped?

Tags: ruby, parameters, controller, escaping

I have a `controller` with PUT method:

```
class UtilsController < ActionController::API
  def update_user_password
    email = params[:email]
    password = params[:password]
    new_password = params[:new_password]
    puts("'#{password}'")    
  end
end
```

and use openapi/javascript and Postman to send password `nRP63P#$`
and in console it logs `nRP63P\#$`

Is `params` of `controller` escaped, and how to get real value? `URI.unescape`?
Reference is welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can unescape value with tools of [Rack](https://github.com/rack/rack)
I think you were looking exactly for this [Rack::Utils#unescape](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack%2FUtils.unescape) method.
So in your case it will be

```rb
unescaped_password = Rack::Utils.unescape(params[:password])
```

Keep in mind that, ruby output by default escapes some special chars `#` is one of them, cause it is indicator of comment, in order to evaluate further code ruby escapes it. So to verify yourself you need to write it to STDOUT or to a file.

```rb
puts unescaped_password
File.open('test.txt', 'w') { |f| f.write(unescaped_password)
```

and then inspect your result.
Do not use `Kernel#pp` or `Kernel#p` or `String#inspect` cause all of them will print values with special chars escaped by ruby itself and can mislead you.

Answer (score 0):

Please compare output with `p` and `puts`

```
password = 'nRP63P#$'

p password # will print "nRP63P\#$"

puts password # will print nRP63P#$
```